# How to submit a click event on a button inside an item in a recylcerview while respecting MVVM architecture?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, viewmodel

I am having a problem, it is technical and conceptual, I am trying to use MVVM architecture and I don't want to drive away from it, so I have a list of items, each item has a delete button, I show the list using recylcerview, so I am using an adapter, now when I call an event on each row I do this :

This is my Adapter, go to deleteBtn inside the ViewHolder.

```
    public class ContractListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContractListAdapter.ContractViewHolder> {

    List<ContractModel> contracts;
    Context context;
    public ContractListAdapter(Context context, List<ContractModel> contracts){
        this.context = context;
        this.contracts = contracts;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ContractViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ContratBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.contrat, parent, false); // ContratBinding >> as your list item layout named "contrat"
        return new ContractViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ContractViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.binding.setContract(contracts.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.contracts.size();
    }

    public class ContractViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        ContractsListViewModel listViewModel;

        @BindView(R.id.courtier)
        TextView courtier;

        @BindView(R.id.delete)
        Button deleteButton;

        ContratBinding binding;

        @BindView(R.id.contratImage)
        ImageView contractImage;

        public ContractViewHolder(@NonNull ContratBinding binding){
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            courtier.setOnClickListener(this);
            deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            contractImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            int idOfContract = contracts.get(position).getId();

            if(deleteButton.getId() == v.getId()){
                // action here
            }
            else {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, ContractActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("key", idOfContract + ""); //Optional parameters
                context.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ContractsListViewModel contractsListViewModel;

    @BindView(R.id.contractList)
    RecyclerView contractList;

    @BindView(R.id.newContractBtn)
    Button newContractBtn;

    @BindView(R.id.listLoading)
    ProgressBar listLoading;

    @BindView(R.id.listError)
    TextView listError;


    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMainBinding main = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        main.contractList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        contractsListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ContractsListViewModel.class);
        contractsListViewModel.call();

        contractsListViewModel.contractList.observe(this,contractModels -> {
            if(contractModels != null){

                contractList.setVisibility((View.VISIBLE));
                adapter = new ContractListAdapter(MainActivity.this, contractModels);
                main.contractList.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

        contractsListViewModel.isLoading.observe(this,isLoading -> {
            if(isLoading != null){
                listLoading.setVisibility(isLoading ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE );
                if(isLoading){
                    listError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    contractList.setVisibility((View.GONE));
                }
            }
        });

        contractsListViewModel.error.observe(this,Error -> {
            if(Error != null){
                listError.setVisibility(Error ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE );
            }
        });

        newContractBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent newContractIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewContractActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(newContractIntent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        contractsListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ContractsListViewModel.class);
        contractsListViewModel.call();
    }
}
```

So when I call an action and observe it I usually do in my MainActivity because I was instanciating my ListViewModel inside the MainActivity, and calling my ViewModel methods, but now I feel like I have to instantiate the same ViewModels in this ViewHolder.

First I don't know how, because when I call 'this' in my MainActivity it refers to MainActvity but If I call it in the ViewHolder ( not an activity ), it won't works, so how will I call my ViewModel in the ViewHolder.

```
contractsListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ContractsListViewModel.class);
```

Second and it is more important, Am I respecting the MVVM architecture if I do this ?

Because how I am conceptualizing it :

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        int idOfContract = contracts.get(position).getId();

        // Delete Button clicked
        if(deleteButton.getId() == v.getId()){

           // I call the ViewModel

           // call the action I want ( delete request )

           // observe it in my MainActivity

        }
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated guys!

Thank you.

Comment: You can do one thing. Make an interface, Get Callback in your activity, Call your `viewModel` method from your activity.

Comment: I did not understand.

Comment: Parth : Any help please ?

Comment: Let me make it more clear to you

Comment: Yes, Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your updated Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ContractsListViewModel contractsListViewModel;

    @BindView(R.id.contractList)
    RecyclerView contractList;

    @BindView(R.id.newContractBtn)
    Button newContractBtn;

    @BindView(R.id.listLoading)
    ProgressBar listLoading;

    @BindView(R.id.listError)
    TextView listError;


    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMainBinding main = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        main.contractList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        contractsListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ContractsListViewModel.class);
        contractsListViewModel.call();

        contractsListViewModel.contractList.observe(this,contractModels -> {
            if(contractModels != null){
                contracts.addAll(contractModels);

                contractList.setVisibility((View.VISIBLE));
                adapter = new ContractListAdapter(MainActivity.this, contractModels, new ContractListAdapter.OnButtonPressed() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClicked(int position) {
                        contractsListViewModel.callDelete(position);
                    }
                });
                main.contractList.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

        contractsListViewModel.isLoading.observe(this,isLoading -> {
            if(isLoading != null){
                listLoading.setVisibility(isLoading ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE );
                if(isLoading){
                    listError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    contractList.setVisibility((View.GONE));
                }
            }
        });

        contractsListViewModel.error.observe(this,Error -> {
            if(Error != null){
                listError.setVisibility(Error ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE );
            }
        });

        newContractBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent newContractIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewContractActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(newContractIntent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        contractsListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ContractsListViewModel.class);
        contractsListViewModel.call();
    }
}
```

This is your updated `ContractListAdapter`

```
public class ContractListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContractListAdapter.ContractViewHolder> {

    List<ContractModel> contracts;
    Context context;
    OnButtonPressed onButtonPressed;

    public ContractListAdapter(Context context, List<ContractModel> contracts,OnButtonPressed onButtonPressed) {
        this.context = context;
        this.contracts = contracts;
        this.onButtonPressed = onButtonPressed;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ContractViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ContratBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.contrat, parent, false); // ContratBinding >> as your list item layout named "contrat"
        return new ContractViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ContractViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.binding.setContract(contracts.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.contracts.size();
    }

    public class ContractViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        ContractsListViewModel listViewModel;

        @BindView(R.id.courtier)
        TextView courtier;

        @BindView(R.id.delete)
        Button deleteButton;

        ContratBinding binding;

        @BindView(R.id.contratImage)
        ImageView contractImage;

        public ContractViewHolder(@NonNull ContratBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            courtier.setOnClickListener(this);
            deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            contractImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            int idOfContract = contracts.get(position).getId();

            if (deleteButton.getId() == v.getId()) {
                // action here
                onButtonPressed.onClicked(position);
            } else {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, ContractActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("key", idOfContract + ""); //Optional parameters
                context.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    interface OnButtonPressed {
        void onClicked(int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooooooooooooh, I thought it is the other way, that is why I did not got your point you and angelina, Thanks so much for this Sir

Comment: Haha, Yes this way you can achieve your goal. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use binding adapter for your button clicks in MVVM architecture with data binding.All your button clicks will be in the same class.

```
<android.support.design.widget.Button
            ...
            android:onClick="@{handlers::ButtonClicked}" />

public class MyClickHandlers {

        public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

Comment: @{handlers::ButtonClicked} handlers is your variableName

Comment: Okay Thanks for that, but it is not an answer to my problem, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a callback function in Activity and let Activity implement it:

```
interface OnDeleteClicklistener {
     void onDelete(int id) 
}
```

Then the activity would call its ViewModel inside this method:

```
void onDelete(int id) {
     viewModel.deleteItem(id)
}
```

Then instead of passing the ViewModel to the Adapter, I would pass the activity as the interface:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(MyAdapter(this, listOfItems)
```

Adapter constructor:

```
MyAdapter(OnDeleteClicklistener listener, List<Item> list)
```

Comment: What do you mean by the activity will call its viewModel inside the method ? I edited the code if you want to be more specific.

Comment: I did not understand your answer

Comment: adapter = new ContractListAdapter(MainActivity.this, contractModels);
                main.contractList.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: This is my Activity passed.

Comment: there is no help ?

Comment: Few comments to your code. Do not pass the `Context` as the first parameter to the adapter. Instead, pass the callback (which is your activity, but you can then call the callback method on it in the adapter. Then why do you set the ViewModel again the `onResume`? This should not be necessary.

Comment: remove `ContractsListViewModel listViewModel;` from the ViewHolder class.

Comment: In `public void onBindViewHolder` method, set the clicklistener to the view, for example `holder.itemView.setOnClicklistener { listener.onDelete(contracts.get(position).getId()) }` I am not very familiar with databinding so I used `itemView` which is the name of the RecyclerView Holder root view. Basically add the click listener to the view and call the callback method there. This will trigger the method in activity and it will then trigger the ViewModel method. Voila!

Comment: I already got an answer, Thanks angelina, also I used resume for refreshing purposes

Comment: It is not necessary to do onResume. It is a waste of resources.

Comment: why ? I was going to an activity and add a new item then when I go back using onBacPressed, I was noticing that my list isn't refreshing, so I implemented this solution and already found it her suggeted by someone. I am new to Android, I am in my 7th day using Android x)

Comment: Good job if you do it only for 7 days! I don’t see all your code but normally it is not necessary, so the problem is somewhere else. Maybe the data is refreshed because you fetch the data in the ViewModel constructor? So then just move the method out of constructor and call it. Anyways, good luck with Android:)